# Bull separate process for job processing unable to catch events on queue

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node.js application i am implementing background job processing using bull module.
I need to catch certain events on the queue like `completed`, `failed`, `error`.

I am trying to have a separate process for process function, but the problem is after moving the job processing to a process function i am unable to catch any of the event like `completed`, `failed`, `error`.

Below is my code

processor.js

```
module.exports =  async function(job, done) {
  try {
    await processExport.performExport(job.data.params, done);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('in error handling');
  };
}
```

worker.js

```
const csvExportProcessing = require('../queue');
csvExportProcessing.process(5, __dirname + '/processor.js');

csvExportProcessing.on('completed', function(job, result){
  console.log('job is now completed');
});

csvExportProcessing.on('failed', function(job, err){
  if(job.attemptsMade == job.opts.attempts) {
    //send a postback
  }
});


csvExportProcessing.on('global:error', function(job, err){
  console.log('Is last attempt?  => ', (job.attemptsMade === job.opts.attempts));
});
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a repo for this? Just curious how you were able to complete this (if you did). Thanks,

Comment: @RizaKhan posted an answer with solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to catch the events using the below code, here is the relevant code to catch `failed` event

```
const myQueue =  process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? new Queue('myqueuename') : new Queue('myqueuename', 'redis://redis:6379/13');
setQueues([myQueue]);
myQueue.on('failed', async function(job, err){
  if(job.attemptsMade == job.opts.attempts) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Was trying to catch 'global:error' without success. 'global:failed' did the trick. In fact I was not able to find the events docs of bull. But after reading your post, here it is: https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#events

Comment: glad it was helpful mate.